# OSX keeps reporting python quit unexpectedly and aborts python

Tags: python, macos, recursion

When I run this program I created to print palindrome primes using recursion (no loops are allowed), apple reports that python quit unexpectedly and aborts and disconnects the shell. However this only happens with rather large inputs, like between 200 - 800.

Is there any reason for this?

my code is:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)
    def isprime(start,end,divisor):
        if start == end:
            return -1
        else:
            if divisor == start:
                a = str(start)
                b = str(start)[::-1]
                if a == b:
                    print(b)            
                return isprime(start+1,end,2)
            elif start%divisor == 0:
                return isprime(start+1,end,2)
            else:
                return isprime(start,end,divisor+1)     

    def main():
        n = eval(input('Enter the starting point N:''\n'))
        m = eval(input('Enter the ending point M:''\n'))
        divisor = 2
        print('The palindromic primes are:')
        primenumbers = isprime(n,m,divisor)

    main()
```

Comment: Try running directly within `Terminal.app` and see what happens.

Comment: `sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)` - don't do that. The Python recursion limit is there to protect you from a C-level stack overflow, which is much messier than a Python stack overflow.

Comment: It is an assignment and they told us to put it in

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you run out of stack frames at around 20K recursions -- you hit this limit about the time you test numbers in the 400's.  I.e. you're using too many stack frames per number.  One way to improve this is to test fewer divisors as each one costs a frame and we're testing more than necessary.  I.e. you're testing 2 to N when you should be testing 2 to sqrt(N) (or even less...)

The other problem is that you don't return any useful result despite the explicit returns and the program expecting a value at the end. Both of these issues are addressed below:

```
import sys
import math

sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)

def ispalindrome(x):
    y = str(x)
    return y == y[::-1]

def ispalindromeprime(start, end, divisor=2):

    palindrome_primes = []

    if start == end:
        pass

    elif divisor > int(math.sqrt(start)):
        if ispalindrome(start):
            print(start)  # optional
            palindrome_primes.append(start)     
        palindrome_primes.extend(ispalindromeprime(start+1, end))

    elif start % divisor == 0:
        palindrome_primes.extend(ispalindromeprime(start+1, end))

    else:
        palindrome_primes.extend(ispalindromeprime(start, end, divisor+1))

    return palindrome_primes

def main():
    n = int(input('Enter the starting point N: '))
    m = int(input('Enter the ending point M: '))

    print('The palindromic primes are:')
    numbers = ispalindromeprime(n, m)
    print(numbers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This bumps your limit from around 400 to around 2500 and returns a list of the palindrome primes:

```
Enter the starting point N: 2
Enter the ending point M: 2500
The palindromic primes are:
2
3
5
7
11
101
131
151
181
191
313
353
373
383
727
757
787
797
919
929
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929]
```

We can push our testing even further by cutting in half the numbers we test, and the divisors we test.  I.e. treat '2' as a special case and only work with odd numbers and divisors:

```
def ispalindromeprime(start, end, divisor=3):

    palindrome_primes = []

    if start >= end:
        pass

    elif start % 2 == 0:
        if start == 2:
            print(start)  # optional
            palindrome_primes.append(start)     
        palindrome_primes.extend(ispalindromeprime(start+1, end))

    elif divisor > int(math.sqrt(start)):
        if ispalindrome(start):
            print(start)  # optional
            palindrome_primes.append(start)     
        palindrome_primes.extend(ispalindromeprime(start+2, end))

    elif start % divisor == 0:
        palindrome_primes.extend(ispalindromeprime(start+2, end))

    else:
        palindrome_primes.extend(ispalindromeprime(start, end, divisor+2))

    return palindrome_primes
```

This bumps your limit to around 4500 though it finds no more results.  (Though it does increase the speed of your program.)

**UPDATE**

We can do even better -- push the limit right up to the limit of the recursion stack itself.  Instead of generating primes and testing if they are palindromes, we can more easily generate palindromes and test if they are primes (other code remains the same):

```
def isprime(number, divisor=3):

    if number <= 2 or number % 2 == 0:
        return number == 2

    if divisor > int(math.sqrt(number)):
        return True

    if number % divisor == 0:
        return False

    return isprime(number, divisor+2)

def ispalindromeprime(n, m):

    palindromeprimes = []

    if n == m:
        return palindromeprimes

    if ispalindrome(n) and isprime(n):
        print(n)  # optional
        palindromeprimes.append(n)

    palindromeprimes.extend(ispalindromeprime(n+1, m))

    return palindromeprimes
```

Now we can push beyond our previous limit, even with a recursive solution:

```
Enter the starting point N: 1
Enter the ending point M: 20000
The palindromic primes are:
2
...
929
10301
10501
10601
11311
11411
12421
12721
12821
13331
13831
13931
14341
14741
15451
15551
16061
16361
16561
16661
17471
17971
18181
18481
19391
19891
19991
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929, 10301, 10501, 10601, 11311, 11411, 12421, 12721, 12821, 13331, 13831, 13931, 14341, 14741, 15451, 15551, 16061, 16361, 16561, 16661, 17471, 17971, 18181, 18481, 19391, 19891, 19991]
```

Since we only need to test the odd numbers (other than 2), we can double this again:

```
def ispalindromeprime(n, m):

    palindromeprimes = []

    if n > m:
        return palindromeprimes

    if ispalindrome(n) and isprime(n):
        print(n)  # optional
        palindromeprimes.append(n)

    if n == 1 or n % 2 == 0:
        n -= 1

    palindromeprimes.extend(ispalindromeprime(n+2, m))

    return palindromeprimes
```

Getting even larger results:

```
Enter the starting point N: 1
Enter the ending point M: 50000
The palindromic primes are:
2
...
19991
30103
30203
30403
30703
30803
31013
31513
32323
32423
33533
34543
34843
35053
35153
35353
35753
36263
36563
37273
37573
38083
38183
38783
39293
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929, 10301, 10501, 10601, 11311, 11411, 12421, 12721, 12821, 13331, 13831, 13931, 14341, 14741, 15451, 15551, 16061, 16361, 16561, 16661, 17471, 17971, 18181, 18481, 19391, 19891, 19991, 30103, 30203, 30403, 30703, 30803, 31013, 31513, 32323, 32423, 33533, 34543, 34843, 35053, 35153, 35353, 35753, 36263, 36563, 37273, 37573, 38083, 38183, 38783, 39293]
```